# Send html through socket in c++

Tags: c++, sockets

I' trying to send html through sockets in c++; after accept the request, my code will call the following function to send arr to client. When I test it on terminal with code of client in c, I received arr. However ,when I tried to connect to port through a web browser, my code shown connect success and send success, but nothing is printed out on browser, it just keep loading. why is that?

```
void sendTCP(int client_socket, vector<string> path)
    {
        cout<<"in sendTCP\n";
        //string web=conWeb(path);
        //cout<<"constructed web is "<<web<<endl;
        char arr[1024]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n<html>\n\r<body>\n\r\rhello\n\r</body>\n</html>";
        int send_res=send(client_socket,arr,sizeof(arr),0);
        if(send_res == -1)
        {
            perror("send");
        }
        else{
            cout<<"send success\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is probably because your response is missing Content-Type, try adding: `Content-Type: text/html` after the 200 status code

Comment: Plus you're sending many hundreds of `0` characters at the end of your response string.

Comment: I have changed arr to this:     char arr[200]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nContent-Type: text/html\n\r\n\r<html>\n\r<body>\n\r\rhello\n\r</body>\n</html>";
    int send_res=send(client_socket,arr,strlen(arr)+1,0);

Comment: but it's stilll not working..

Comment: If you're using C++, don't use char*. Use std::string, it's safer, less verbose, easier and often more legible (vector<char> is another option). To send you would use the .data() member to get the const char* and .size() to send the data without any null or size()+1 to include the null.

Comment: Also, pass a (const) reference in path, you're otherwise copying the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```html
char arr[200]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\nContent-Length: 16\n\n<h1>testing</h1>";
int send_res=send(sock,arr,sizeof(arr),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try restructuring the string

```
arr="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\nContent-Length: 16\n\n<h1>testing</h1>"
```